# Android SlidingMenu not showing with SlidingFragmentActivity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

Problem: My sliding menu only show empty view(with white background)

I use sliding menu which is widely used for facebook-like menu. (https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

But in my project, sliding menu is not showing any layout but only shows white background.

I've used sliding menu in my other projects before without any problem.

The big difference is I use actionbarsherlock in my new Project (And pager adapter).

Below is class definition of my Main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {
```

And modify sliding menu libarary like below to support actionbar

```
public class SlidingFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements SlidingActivityBase {
```

And setup sliding Menu as below in my main activity:

```
private void setupSlidingMenu(){

    setBehindContentView(myMenu);

    menu = getSlidingMenu();
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
}
```

I also test both very simple layout with one textview and simple Fragment but both trial shows same result.

Both my project and sliding menu library have dependency on ActionbarSherlock library.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: I found out the reason but no idea why this happen. I use android:theme="@style/WhiteTheme.VPI" in my menifest and this is why my sliding menu only shows empty space. <style name="WhiteTheme.VPI" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
       <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomTabPageIndicator</item>
       <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/WhiteTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
     <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/WhiteTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
     
     <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
    </style> Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by myself.

Problem is that I use below theme in my main activity.

```
<style name="WhiteTheme.VPI" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light"> 
    <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomTabPageIndicator</item> 
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/WhiteTheme.ActionBarStyle</item> 
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/WhiteTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item> 
</style>
```

And `<item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>` make whole my sliding menu white and hiding every layout. Don't actually understand why this attribute hide everything.